# How to solve $x^2 - 4^x = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solving the following equation

$$x^{100} - 4^xx^{98} - x^2 + 4^x = 0$$

yielded

$$(x^2 - 4^x)(x^{98} - 1) = 0$$

From the right term on the left side, I get the solutions $x = \pm 1$, but I'm unsure how to solve the left term on the left side without using Wolfram. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Hint:** [*Lambert W-Function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) or numerical methods, like [*Newton's Method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: "precalculus" means that you can't differentiate, but you can plot the functions and "see" the solution that is about $x=-0.6$, where the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=4^x$ have a point of intersection

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the square root of both sides to get

$$x=\pm2^x$$

We can see that

$$x=2^x$$

has no solutions, since for $x\le0$, we have

$$x\le0<2^x$$

And for $x>0$, we have

$$2^x>x\ln(2)>x$$

However, it is easy to see that

$$x=-2^x$$

has solutions, since

$$f(x)=x+2^x$$

is continuous and $f(-1)<0<f(0)$. This solution may be found using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), as follows:

$$x=-2^x=-e^{x\ln(2)}$$

$$-x\ln(2)e^{-x\ln(2)}=\ln(2)$$

$$-x\ln(2)=W(\ln(2))$$

> $$x=-\frac{W(\ln(2))}{\ln(2)}=-e^{-W(\ln(2))}\approx−0.641185744505$$

To calculate this root, we may implement an Euler-like iteration method, noticing that $(-2^x)'<0$.

$$a_n=\begin{cases}t,&n=0\\\cfrac{a_{n-1}-2^{a_{n-1}+1}}3,&n>0\end{cases}$$

For any $t\in\Bbb[-1,0]$, we have,

$$x=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$

For example, with $t=0$, we have

$$a_8\approx-0.641185744508$$

There are various ways to improve this method. By properly weighting terms, we can derive an even faster converging sequence:

$$b_n=\begin{cases}t,&n=0\\\cfrac{b_{n-1}^2\ln(2)+2^{b_{n-1}}}{b_{n-1}\ln(2)-1},&n>0\end{cases}$$

With $t=0$, we get

$$b_5\approx-0.641185744511$$

Asymptotically, when $t=0$, we have

$$a_n=x-\mathcal O\big(0.03705^n\big)$$

$$b_n=x-\mathcal O\big(|0.5865x|^{2^n}\big)$$

(assuming I did that correctly)

Notice how quickly $b_n$ converges compared to $a_n$!

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 - 4^x = 0\Longleftrightarrow \ln |x| = x \ln 2\Longleftrightarrow f(x)= 0 $$

Where $f(x) =\ln | x| -x\ln 2$

$$f'(x) =  \frac{1}{x}-\ln 2=0\implies x= \frac{1}{\ln 2} $$

But $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$$

**Hence on $(0,\infty)$ $f$** reach its maximum at $\frac{1}{\ln 2}$ but 
$$f\left(\frac{1}{\ln 2}\right) = \ln \frac{1}{\ln 2} -1<0 \implies f(x)<0 \forall~~,x>0$$
So the equation $f(x) = 0$ has no solution on $(0,\infty)$

**But on  $(-\infty,0)$ we have** that $f$ is strictly decreasing and
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) = -\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \infty$$
Therefore the equation $f(x)=0$ has only one  solutions $x_1$ such that:
 $$-1<x_1< -\frac{1}{2}.$$

Since $$f(-1) = \ln2>0\quad\text{and}\quad f(-\frac{1}{2}) =-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2<0$$

Comment: What does this mean? For example, try $$x \approx -0.641185744504986$$

Comment: In fact $x^2-4^x = 0$ if and only if $\ln |x| = x\ln 2$, and this equation has a solution when $x<0$ (as pointed out by Moo).

Comment: What do i have to do with that value?

Comment: It's a solution to the equation $x^2-4^x=0$.

Comment: @GuyFsone: Substitute it into $$x^2 - 4^x$$ You can also plot the function to see it.

Comment: Ok thank for this notification it was a big mistake. But now it should be fine

Comment: It's still wrong: $\ln \frac{1}{\ln 2} - 1 < 0$, and indeed, there are no positive solutions to the equation $f(x)=0$. There is only one real solution to the equation $x^2-4^x=0$ (or equivalently $f(x)=0$), and that solution is negative.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: Thank you for all your comments and catching that last bit!

Comment: It is alright now.Only one solution. Thank for correcting my mistake

Comment: @CliveNewstead you are right and the solution should be in $-1<x_1< -\frac{1}{2}.$ which give some closer precision ]

Comment: Still doesn't really answer the question as to how one *solves* for $x$.